# how to access postgres from mysql?

Tags: mysql, postgresql, federated

Is it possible to access a Postgres database from MySQL, so that I could run a single query that does joins across tables in both databases?

For example:

```
SELECT * FROM postgres.db1.table1 as t1, mysql.db2,table2 WHERE t1.id=t2.id;
```

Answer (score 4):

According to the MySQL [CREATE SERVER](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-server.html) documentation:

> The wrapper_name should be *mysql*, and may be quoted with single quotation marks. **Other values for wrapper_name are not currently supported**.

So the answer is **no**, you cannot do that at the moment, but you can [access the MySQL server from within PostgreSQL](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Foreign_data_wrappers#mysql_fdw) instead.

Comment: If you use `mysql_fdw` in PostgreSQL it'll work, but probably perform pretty poorly as it's quite limited in how it executes cross-server joins using FDWs.