# How to use Federated Engine(Mysql) to Postgresql Table Migration

Tags: mysql, postgresql, federated-table

I tried using migrate mysql to postgresql. It Exist error for Below Message.

**Erro Message:** 11:05:39  SELECT * FROM fed_orders LIMIT 0, 1000  Error Code: 1159. Got timeout reading communication packets 30.051 sec.

**Steps Used:**

a) Activate Federated Engine in Mysql.

```
Configure /etc/my.cnf , add 'federated' keyword in [mysqld] section, then restart mysql Service.
```

b) Create Federated Server

```
CREATE SERVER fedlink FOREIGN DATA WRAPPER mysql OPTIONS (USER 'postgres', HOST '103.93.107.148', PORT 5432, DATABASE 'MOA_DB');
```

b) Link mysql table with fedlink server

```
CREATE TABLE fed_orders (
id     INT(20),
name   VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL DEFAULT '') ENGINE=FEDERATED DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 CONNECTION='fedlink/fed_orders';
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to access postgres from mysql?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26385118/how-to-access-postgres-from-mysql)

Comment: yes .. i also want duplicate mysql table to postgres table

Comment: Was this a reply to my comment? The point of my comment (and the duplicate flag) was: read the other question, it asked basically the same thing. And the answer to that question was that you cannot access postgres from mysql, you can just connect to other *mysql* servers from mysql. And that is the exact answer to your question too: you just cannot to it (yet), that is why you get an error message. You can however connect *from* postgres *to* mysql (but that would be a different question). And if you really want to migrate (copy once), there are tools for that (and also a different question).

Comment: Ok. I agree. What was the sollution for sending mysql data into postgres..

Comment: For the opposite direction, have a look at (e.g.) [Setup Mysql Foreign Data Wrapper in Postgresql](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41576892/6248528)